# Change/add text to current user@server

Tags: linux, terminal

Its kinda hard to pick a good title, sorry for that!

When you login to Linux, you see the user and the domain where you can type your commands.

`[user@location domain.nl]$ mv ~/example ~/my-new-example`.

I have 2 servers which almost are identical. Can i change the user@location text or add something to it like

`[my-own-text-here]$ mv ~/example ~/my-new-example`

Comment: Googling bash prompt or reading the bash manual will show you this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by editing your `/etc/bashrc` file or by creating a custom shell script in `/etc/profile.d`

If you want to edit the `bashrc`, find this line (be sure to make a backup of at least this line if not the whole file in case you make a mistake):

`[ "$PS1" = "\\s-\\v\\\$ " ] && PS1="[\u@\h \W]\\$ "`

The second `PS1` is using `\u@\h` which is user@hostname. You can change that to whatever you'd like. For example, if one is a database server then you can change it to `PS1="[\u@DBSERVER \W]\\$ "` and if the other is a web server then you can change it to `PS1="[\u@WEBSERVER \W]\\$ "`

Afterward, enter `bash` and you'll see the text change. The users will see it if they do the same or the next time they log in.

Just to add one more time, make a backup before you make any changes.